# tornado callback inside a thread

Tags: python, callback, threadpool, tornado

In the example code below I am trying to create a webserver with a threadpool to handle the get request.In the send_result() (which gets called by from a thread), I have used tornado callback as the document is saying to use main thread to trigger the finish or write on a request.

Thread safety doc link: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#thread-safety-notes

If I call the API **localhost:4400/** it is stalling. I m not getting any response from the server

Please help me with this, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import asynchronous
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/', DataHandler)
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def handle_error(self, ex):
        def to_do():
            self.set_status(500)
            self.finish(str(ex))
        IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=to_do)

    def send_result(self, ret_val):
        def to_do():
            self.set_status(200)
            self.finish(ret_val)
        IOLoop.instance().add_callback(callback=to_do)

class DataHandler(BaseHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self):
        def to_do():
            try:
                self.send_result("hi")
            except Exception as ex:
                self.handle_error(ex)
        pool.apply_async(to_do)

pool = None

def main():
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(4400)
    global pool
    pool = ThreadPool(10)
    print("Server started and listening on 4400")
    IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This looks OK to me but I'm not familiar with `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`. The recommended thread pool for use with Tornado is `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. By using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and coroutines you can avoid a lot of the explicit passing callback back and forth between threads.

Comment: @BenDarnell Thanks for the comment This code is working fine with the older version of tornado (ver: 4.4.2, after posting only I come to know) but with the newer version, I am facing the problem. Could you please share any example code to use the Threadpoolexecutor?

Comment: See the third option in http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=threadpoolexecutor#why-isn-t-this-example-with-time-sleep-running-in-parallel